# Name of validation custom objects properties

Tags: javascript

My question is, Is this a correct validation?
And if it is, then what is the name of the type of validation?

I tried to use this and it doesn't work:

```
const existsProperty = data?.author
```

Also, I tried this validation and it works, what is the name of this type of validation?

```
const existsProperty = !!data.author
```

Comment: ```const existsProperty = data?.author !== undefined;```, If ```author``` not exists then it will returns ```undefined```.

Comment: thanks i found the answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining